# XcodeBuild command line is failed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I have sample hello world program in swiftUI, I have added [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess)

When I try to run the app using Xcode, it works fine,
But if I run using Terminal command `Xcodebuild`

then it shows error like **No much module for import KeychainAccess**

I added library as swift package manager.